# rapidfuzz install issues caused by cmake

Tags: cmake, raspberry-pi4, redbot

Sys info

```
PRETTY_NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)"
NAME="Raspbian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="10"
VERSION="10 (buster)"
VERSION_CODENAME=buster
ID=raspbian
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianForums"
BUG_REPORT_URL="http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianBugs"
```

Having trouble installing a package (rapidfuzz) I seem to be having an issue with cmake.
I am trying to install it inside a pyenv
The commands used.

`pyenv shell ATOM`

`pip install --force-reinstall --no-cache-dir rapidfuzz`

[Error Message](https://pastebin.com/U25SiLfF)

I have tried to reinstall cmake but the issue still persists.

The package is for a [discord bot](https://docs.discord.red/en/stable/index.html) I have tried asking them but all they know is the issue is with cmake

Comment: Anyone? Could use the help

Answer (score 0):

You should report issues like this directly to the project. I opened an issue regarding this on github: https://github.com/maxbachmann/RapidFuzz/issues/223. This particular issue appears to be caused by the cmake build system, which was introduced in v2.0.0. So you can avoid this issue by using an older version of rapidfuzz for now:

```py
pip install rapidfuzz==1.9.1
```